# Find the indices of all elements of an array in a second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two arrays, I would like to find the indices of the elements of one of those in the other, and get a new array with said indices, and a `-1` for elements not present in the second array.

For example, given two arrays:

```
x = np.array([ 0, 17, 94, 3, 25])
y = np.array([ 1, 14, 0, 3, 27, 0, 17, 94, 52])
```

I want:

```
z = np.array([ -1, -1, 0, 3, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1])
```

I've looked at `np.intersect1d` but I think it is not what I'm after.

Edit: I'm working with big arrays (around 10 or 15 million elements each), so performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([np.where(x==i)[0][0] if i in x else -1 for i in y])
```

edit:

This may not scale well :)